# Can't find Run in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I just want to run a simple java code. But I can't find the Run button. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you have it. The green triangle on the top toolbar is it.

Comment: I don't know if you ever used Android Studio. But that one starts the emulator.

Comment: It starts the emulator and launches your app on the device. If you want to run on another device, choose from the pull-down menu just left of the button.

Comment: connect your phone through a USB cable be sure that the USB debugging is on your device then your device name is shown on the emulator name and the android studio runs your app to your phone.

Comment: @hata is right, seems you need to review the basic documentation of Android Studio https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device

Comment: Why are you trying to use _Android_ Studio to run a command-line Java program that has nothing to do with _Android_?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is shown in the below image
[image]

Comment: That one launches Emulator :)

Comment: Do you want to run the project on your phone?

Comment: Nah, I just want to run it on terminal

Comment: @NathanKlero If you just want to run a Java program, you may not use Android Studio but use IntelliJ or Eclipse.

Comment: If you want to run your code run on the terminal then you have no need for the UI. In the current situation, you have the activity and defined in the manifest file that's why it's run on the emulator because it is the default launcher activity. that's why your code opens the emulator.

Comment: Maybe you should reformulate the question. You don't mention that you want to run on a terminal.